# Show that exist a unique expression for $ A $ of the form $ A = (A_1 + A_2) + i (B_1 + B_2) $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ A $ be a $ n × n $ matrix with real or complex elements. Show that exist a unique expression for $ A $ of the form

$$ A = (A_1 + A_2) + i (B_1 + B_2) $$

where $ A_1,B_1$ are real symmetric matrices and $ A_2,B_2 $ are real antisymmetric matrices

Comment: @AWertheim, if you were attempting to answer his question, please write it as an "answer"

Comment: @dineshdileep My apologies. I figured since my contributions weren't substantive it was better left as a comment, but I can delete them and post it as an answer.

Comment: @AWertheim       Thanks for your time and help :D

Comment: @user63192 my pleasure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to show is that any real square matrix can be written as the sum of a symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix. This is shown really nicely here.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AntisymmetricMatrix.html

To show uniqueness, suppose there are two representations of a matrix, $R_{1} + R_{2}$ and $S_{1} + S_{2}$, where $R_{1}, S_{1}$ are symmetric and $R_{2}, S_{2}$ are antisymmetric. Then we have $R_{1} + R_{2} = S_{1} + S_{2}$, which implies $R_{1} - S_{1} = S_{2} - R_{2}$. But the left side is symmetric and the right side is antisymmetric, and the only matrix which is both symmetric and antisymmetric is the zero matrix. So we have $R_{1} = S_{1}$ and $R_{2} = S_{2}$.